# When does ‘trotz’ govern the dative case?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case, dative, genitive

It is said that *trotz* historically went well with both the dative and the genitive cases, while in contemporary usage the genitive becomes the norm and the dative survives only in idiomatic ‘frozen’ expressions. 
My difficulty is with those special cases when the dative case is used instead of the genitive. I have no idea when the dative **must** be used.

It seems to me that the so-called idiomatic expressions are a bunch of combinations of pronouns and *trotz,* such as *trotzdem, trotz allem/alledem.*
Could I conclude that when *trotz* goes with a pronoun, the dative case should be used instead of the genitive while with a noun, the genitive should be used?

If my claim is wrong, could anyone provide some tip on when the dative case **must** be used instead of the genitive with *trotz*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/Genitiv.html#Anchor-trotz-30408) sums it up nicely. The general rule is: Use genitive. Then the following exceptions apply:

- Since genitive plural is unmarked, *always* use dative plural if there is no article and there are no adjectives;
- *Always* use (uninflected) dative singular for single nouns without adjectives or article;
- You *may* use dative if the noun has no article, only adjectives;
- You *may* always use dative colloquially;
- The forms *trotzdem, trotz Allem* and *trotz alledem* require their dative case.

In the end, it turns out that there seem to be more exceptions than rules, however, it does still seem to be more concise writing it this way rather than reversed (*use dative unless …*).

Comment: thanks for your answer ; I am a bit doubtful over this 'Always use (uninflected) dative singular for single nouns without adjectives or article'; for in such cases of single nouns, the genitive marks the case more clearly than the uninflected dative ; for example, to me ,,trotz Frosts und Schnees'' seems better than ,,trotz Frost und Schnee'' ;

Comment: @Lynnyo But *trotz Frost und Schnee* is more usual.

Comment: Good advice for a non-native speaker. As a native speaker I can confidently always use dative, because that is the case that goes with “trotzen”.

Comment: (Ok, to be honest, I only wished I was that confident.)

Comment: @Jan : is the usage of ,,trotz'' with the dative case CORRELATED to the case government of the verb ,,trotzen''? I mean, 'to defy sb./sth.' in German is ,, j-m./etwas(dat.) trotzen'' and this dative case in the verbal phrase is preserved to some degree into the prepositional phrase?

Comment: @Lynnyo Whether *trotz* (the preposition) and *trotzen* (the verb) have any etymologic connection, and if so, whether that is the reason why *trotz* governed dative may be the basis of a good question ;)

Comment: @Jan : According to Canoo, there are occasions when the dative case MUST be used; however, I am very concerned about the colloquial style endowed with it; could one use ,,trotz+dative'' in such formal registers as academic writing?

Comment: @Lynnyo See bullet points one and two (and five). *Trotz* + noun without modifiers in genitive plural is considered *wrong*, so it can never be *trotz Gegenbeweise*, it has to be *trotz Gegenbeweise**n.***